# The <blockquote> style in the meta markdown preview is not consistent with the actual style

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Here's what it looks like in the meta markdown preview:

[image: meta markdown preview of a blockquote]

and here is how it looks when posted:

> This is a blockquote

The styling is consistent on the main site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed, it'll be live after our next production build.